# Windows 10 pro does not boot from SSD

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd

My laptop has 2 drives: SSD and HDD. Originally the SSD was 60gb. It was upgraded to 240gb. The HDD is 1000gb.  Both drives have a Windows partition.  I don't know why, since I inherited the laptop from another person. The SSD has Win10 pro, which was upgraded from Win10 Home.  Over the weekend the PC stopped booting from the SSD.

In legacy BIOS mode it boots from neither drive. In UEFI BIOS mode it boots from the HDD but gives a limited version of Windows, with no start menu. Basic windows utilities can be run from the command prompt. I have Windows Explorer, Device Manager, and Computer Manager all running.

I notice the Drive C: and D: have been swapped; but Disk 0 and 1 remain as they were. The HDD is still Disk 1, but now labelled C:  The SSD is Disk 0 and labelled D:

I ran a disk check on the SSD but found no errors. Windows Defender finds no virus. Computer Management, Disk Management report

### Disk 0 :

```
100 MB, Healthy (EFI, System Partition) 
D:, NTFS, 220.87gb, Healthy, (Wim Boot, Primary Partition)
450 MB, Healthy (Recovery Partition)
11.35 GB, Healthy (Recovery Partition)
```

### Disk 1 :

```
100 MB, Healthy (EFI, System Partition)
C:, NTFS; 930.85gb, Healthy, (Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Primary Partition)
450 MB, Healthy (Recovery Partition)
```

Those are my 7 Primary Partitions.

Questions:

Q1: Why did Windows swap the boot drives around like that?
Q2: Why will neither drive boot using Legacy BIOS?
Q3: How can I fix it?
Q4: Am I right in thinking that I need to make a recovery partition on a DVD, CD, or USB, and boot from that. Run Diskpart, and swap the bootable partitions over?
Q5: I cannot make a recovery partition from this PC. Can I make a recovery partition from another (Win10 Home) PC instead?

PS1: The O/S on the SSD is Win10 Pro.
PS2: I'm almost certain the "11.35 GB, Healthy (Recovery Partition)" will be Win10 Home (what it originally was)
PS3: This laptop is an Acer Nitro VN7-591G

Comment: I left the PC on running with the Win10 Home (loaded from the HHD). It automatically ran a Windows Update. I allowed it to run its proper course. But set the PC to power down. Next day I powered up, and all was magically fixed.  It boots Win10 Pro from the SSD now!

Answer (score 0):

> Why did Windows swap the boot drives around like that?

Because it wants to keep C: as the boot drive.

> Why will neither drive boot using Legacy BIOS?

Because Windows was installed in UEFI mode. Why do you need to use legacy mode?

The "limited version of Windows" doesn't sound like a boot problem, since Windows has booted. I suspect your Windows installation is broken somehow.